# Counting distinct values for a given column partitioned by a window function, without using approx_count_distinct()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
val df1 = Seq(("Roger","Rabbit", "ABC123"), ("Roger","Rabit", "ABC123"),("Roger","Rabbit", "ABC123"), ("Trevor","Philips","XYZ987"), ("Trevor","Philips","XYZ987")).toDF("first_name", "last_name", "record")

+----------+---------+------+
|first_name|last_name|record|
+----------+---------+------+
|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|
|Roger     |Rabit    |ABC123|
|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|
|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|
|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|
+----------+---------+------+
```

I want to group records in this dataframe by the column `record`. And then I want to look for anomalies in the fields `first_name` and `last_name`, which should remain constant for all records with same `record` value.

The best approach I found so far is using `approx_count_distinct`:

```
val wind_person = Window.partitionBy("record")

df1.withColumn("unique_fields",cconcat($"first_name",$"last_name"))
.withColumn("anomaly",capprox_count_distinct($"unique_fields") over wind_person)
.show(false)    


+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|first_name|last_name|record|unique_fields|anomaly|
+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|RogerRabbit  |2      |
|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|RogerRabbit  |2      |
|Roger     |Rabit    |ABC123|RogerRabit   |2      |
|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|1      |
|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|1      |
+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```

Where an anomaly is detected is `anomaly` column is greater than 1.

The problem is with `approx_count_distinct` we get just an approximation, and I am not sure how much confident we can be that it will always return an accurate count.

Some extra information:

- The Dataframe may contain over 500M records
- The Dataframe is previously repartitioned based on `record` column
- For each different value of `record`, no more than 15 rows will be there

Is is safe to use `approx_count_distinct` in this scenario with a 100% accuracy or are there better window functions in spark to achieve this?

Comment: To reproduce the scenario add: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_set` of `unique_fields` over the window `wind_person` and get it's size which is equivalent to the count distinct of that field :

```
df1.withColumn("unique_fields", concat($"first_name", $"last_name"))
  .withColumn("anomaly", size(collect_set($"unique_fields").over(wind_person)))
  .show

//+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
//|first_name|last_name|record|unique_fields|anomaly|
//+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
//|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|RogerRabbit  |2      |
//|Roger     |Rabit    |ABC123|RogerRabit   |2      |
//|Roger     |Rabbit   |ABC123|RogerRabbit  |2      |
//|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|1      |
//|Trevor    |Philips  |XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|1      |
//+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact `countDistinct` over a Window using some `dense_rank` operations:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "unique_fields", 
    concat($"first_name",$"last_name")
).withColumn(
    "anomaly", 
    dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("record").orderBy("unique_fields")) + 
    dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("record").orderBy(desc("unique_fields"))) 
    - 1
)

df2.show
+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|first_name|last_name|record|unique_fields|anomaly|
+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|     Roger|    Rabit|ABC123|   RogerRabit|      2|
|     Roger|   Rabbit|ABC123|  RogerRabbit|      2|
|     Roger|   Rabbit|ABC123|  RogerRabbit|      2|
|    Trevor|  Philips|XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|      1|
|    Trevor|  Philips|XYZ987|TrevorPhilips|      1|
+----------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```